# Is it possible to run an ASP.NET project and an ASP.NET MVC project side-by-site on the same website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, routes, asp.net-3.5, projects-and-solutions

I have an existing ASP.NET website with some custom routing, within a Solution that also contains Business Logic projects.

I want to create a new project within the Solution, which is an ASP.NET MVC website.

This website will also call the Business logic, and the ultimate aim is to port most of the code from ASP.NET to ASP.NET MVC.

But I want them to both work side-by-side for now, to ensure minimal down-time, as it's a high-traffic website.

Is it possible to accomplish this somehow using either ASP.NET routing or some kind of IIS setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, you just need to add some routing to your current application.  Try http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

**Please have a look at [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx) post by Scott HanselMan.**
It provides detailed discussion about this along with a nice walk through.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a [blog post](http://www.mattwrock.com/post/2009/09/15/Colocatng-ASPNET-MVC-and-Web-Forms-in-the-same-Web-Application.aspx) on this. It is possible. You might find it easier to simply relocate your web forms from your existing web forms project to your new MVC project. You may not have to change any code.